# How to wait for navigator.getUserMedia to be done?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to create an object called Recorder like this `rec = new Recorder(input, { numChannels: 1 });`. I need to initialize the audio context as `audioSetter = new AudioContext()` and call the navigator.getUserMedia

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
        { audio: true },
        (stream) => {
            gumStream = stream;
            input = audioSetter.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        },
        (err) => console.log(`No live audio input: ${err}`)
    );
```

from which I need input. The problem is input is not defined when I call the Recorder object. I managed to make a promise with a timeout so I got the value:

`setTimeout(() => {resolve();}, 200); // wait a little for media stream`

But this is ugly and the 200ms is set by trial and error which can always change. How could I write this better? I've also tried with async/await but I got the same results.

Comment: `getUserMedia` returns a promise that you can await

Comment: And it does not accept a second or third argument.

Comment: @Pointy [It does, actually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

Comment: @Konrad You're thinking of [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: @Bergi ah I was looking at the Media versionm *edit* `MediaDevices`

Comment: "*I managed to make a promise*" - just resolve/reject the promise from the callbacks. Or use the non-deprecated version of the API :)

Comment: You mean AudioWorklet, right? If yes, I can't use it because it doesn't work on manifest V3 ( for chrome extensions ) or at least I didn't manage to make it work.